# Using Schema.post to add an expiration date based on date in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my Mongoose Schema, I have a typical createdAt field.

```
createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now()
```

},

I also have a field called endDate, it's part of a startDate and endDate thing I have going for showing appointments

```
endDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Please add an end date']
  }
```

So I'm attempting to use Schema.post to add an expires field to the createdAt, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
EventSchema.post('save', async function() {
  const expirationTimeInSeconds = (new Date(this.endDate) - new Date(this.createdAt)) / 1000; 
  
  console.log('event expires in:')
  console.log(expirationTimeInSeconds);

  this.createdAt = {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: expirationTimeInSeconds
  };

});
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could set my model to expire at the endDate?

I expected it to add the expires field.